# Using boost locale generator correctly

Tags: c++, boost, locale, utf

I want to store `utf8` characters in my `std::strings`. For that I used `boost::locale` conversion routines.

In my first test everything works as expected:

```
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

std::string utf8_string = boost::locale::conv::to_utf<char>("Grüssen", "ISO-8859-15");
std::string normal_string = boost::locale::conv::from_utf(utf8_string, "ISO-8859-15");
```

The expected Result is:

```
utf8_string = "GrÃ¼ssen"
normal_string = "Grüssen"
```

To get rid of passing "ISO-8859-15" as string I tried to use `std::locale` instead.

```
// Create system default locale
boost::locale::generator gen;
std::locale loc=gen("ISO8859-15"); 
std::locale::global(loc); 
// This is needed to prevent C library to
// convert strings to narrow 
// instead of C++ on some platforms
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

std::string utf8_string = boost::locale::conv::to_utf<char>("Grüssen", std::locale());
std::string normal_string = boost::locale::conv::from_utf(utf8_string, std::locale());
```

But the result is not as expected:

```
utf8_string = "Gr|ssen"
normal_string = "Gr|ssen"
```

What's wrong with my use of using `std::locale` and generator?
(Compiler VC2015, charset multibyte)

Comment: How do you inspect the results? It's weird to "expect" `utf8_string = "GrÃ¼ssen"` since essentially you "expect" wrong decoding there. Also, what is the source file encoding? If it's anything else than latin1, it's wrong.

Comment: I inspected it with the VC2015 Debugger and i used win32 TextOutA to print the normal_string, that was  back converted from utf8. Notepad++ tells me the file encoding is ANSI. Well, to see the utf_8 string  GrÃ¼ssen" is not weired, because "GrÃ¼sse" is the way the utf8-encoded Grüsse looks when you render it with something expecting iso8859-1. So what is wrong with the std::locale use here and why does the second version works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::locale::generator` wants a *locale id*, not merely an encoding (the same encoding may be used by multiple locales). The scheme it uses is `language_country.encoding`, so you'll need `de_DE.ISO-8859-15`.

Also, you're playing with fire by putting non-ASCII characters within your source code. Be careful.

Your comment about `sync_with_stdio()` is also weird. It just makes sure buffers are flushed.

Comment: `sync_with_stdio()` makes sure buffers are /not/ unnecessarily flushed between C/C++ IO **and** removes requirements for thread synchronization. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio